# How to use fallback component in react native bugsnag?

Tags: react-native, bugsnag

I am using bugsnag in react native to track bugs and I want fallback to custom component when error occurs. For React fall back component mentioned in docs. But in react native I didn't find. How to use this. Help me out

Answer (score 0):

You're best contacting Bugsnag support directly to get a quick response to queries about the product.

Bugsnag doesn't yet support error boundaries in React Native like we do for React but we plan to in the near future. We're also about to start officially supporting Expo as a platform and will be supporting error boundaries on that.

Thanks!